# Local self signed certificate works in Firefox but not Chrome?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, firefox, https, ssl-certificate

In Firefox I can go to a test local server:

https://localhost:3000/

However in Chrome I get this error:

> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost
> (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

This is on my localhost and I have even manually added the self-signed certificate to Chrome.

I followed these directions [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-get-ssl-https-for-localhost/):

and this is the screen were I added the cert:

[image]

Comment: Google pushed a new **pos** feature (IMHO) that blocks all self-signed certificates, and all encryption below TLSv1.2 in the latest version of the browser.  It is a pain for test or dev sites, or older sites and consoles.  Nothing you can do about it.  It was updated yesterday on all PC at work this weekend, it caused a small panic!

Comment: What is this new pos feature?  Is there a google doc online I can read?

Comment: oups sorry, pos == piece of s...t :)  you can look at the release notes from google.

Comment: oh ... pos, means point of sale to me ... I found this bizarre setting in Chrome ... chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost ... on this post ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

Comment: ah, I will try this out, but form what I was told, this workaround was not available anymore.    I'll confirm on Monday at work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But a bit different scenario. 
For my self-signed **server** certificate I have NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID,
but for another **client** certificate I have NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID (this does not allow to proceed)

I was generated these certs with help of *KeyStore Explorer* app.
And there you can add already prepared template like 'SSL Server' or 'SSL Client':
[image: ui with templates]

So, 'SSL Server' had **expected** ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID warning and SSL Client has the error from the topic. (ERR_CERT_INVALID)
The difference is in the option of "Extended Key Usage" extension.
[image]